# NodeJS process exit is not running SQL query

Tags: node.js, nodes

The below NodeJS app is running perfectly fine without process.exit() when I add process.exit() it closes the window after executing (which I what I am after) but it's not executing the SQL query.

```
var mysql = require('mysql')

var conn = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10000,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "mydatabase",
  port: 3306
});

var values = ""
for (var i=0; i < 300; i++) {
  var pub = //some randomvalue
  var hub = //some randomvalue
  values += "('"+pub + "', '" + hub + "'), "
  console.log(i);
  }
var valuesx = values.slice(0, -2)
var sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (pub, hub) VALUES "
var sqlx = sql + valuesx;
conn.getConnection(function(err, con) {
if (err) throw err
 con.query(sqlx)
 con.release();
});
process.exit(0)
```

**The above code doesn't insert into MySQL**

**If I remove process.exit(0) it inserts into MySQL**

Comment: You're exiting before the callback executes. You need to exit AFTER the callback executes - and that means INSIDE THE CALLBACK. Remember, everything OUTSIDE of the callback happens BEFORE the callback

Comment: @slebetman  I tried adding it after con.release() but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
conn.getConnection(function(err, con) {
if (err) throw err
 con.query(sqlx, function (err2, result) {
  if (err2) throw err;
  con.release(); 
  process.exit(0)
  // you should put these inside this callback
 })
 
});
```

Comment: Why are you calling `process.exit(0)` before calling `con.release()`?  Why are you not checking for errors and doing something useful on either database call?

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for pointing out the issues. I have changed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to not call `process.exit()` until your query has completed by moving the call inside the completion callback for the query.  You also need some work on your error handling so you log errors and cleanup properly when there's an error:

```
conn.getConnection(function(err, con) {
    // need real error handling here too as just a throw err won't do anything useful
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    con.query(sqlx, function(err, data) {
        let exitCode = 0;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            exitCode = 2;
        }
        con.release();
        process.exit(exitCode);
    });
});
```